# Problem referencing relative folder/file Path from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling to reference my file to my html files using relative path. It would show a unstyled html page when opening in a browser or opening in Ed Workspace. However, everything works fine if I opened it via live server. My file/folder management is attached below and here is one of my html code. I think I have got the relative path correct but I have no idea why it wouldn't work in browsers.

...

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Index/Indexcss.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="/Library/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="/Index/indexjs.js"></script>
    <title>Outsidermm</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="FrontText">
        <p class="Firstname">Xujing</p>
        <p class="Lastname">MAO</p>
    </div>

    <img
        class="JM_Logo"
        src="/Media/Logo/png/logo-no-background.png"
        alt="logo"
    />

    <a href="/Introduction/Introduction.html">
        <button class="explore_button" type="button">Explore</button>
    </a>
</body>
```

...

[Folder Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smhHK.png)

Comment: If your index.html lives in the same folder as your css file, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Indexcss.css" />` should do the trick for your CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is relative to each individual document.

Given your folder structure and location of the index file, here is how you would set it up:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Indexcss.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"         rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Library/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="indexjs.js"></script>
    <title>Outsidermm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="FrontText">
        <p class="Firstname">Xujing</p>
        <p class="Lastname">MAO</p>
    </div>
    <img
        class="JM_Logo"
        src="../Media/Logo/png/logo-no-background.png"
        alt="logo" />
    <a href="../Introduction/Introduction.html">
        <button class="explore_button" type="button">Explore</button>
    </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Index/Indexcss.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="Library/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="Index/indexjs.js"></script>
    <title>Outsidermm</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="FrontText">
        <p class="Firstname">Xujing</p>
        <p class="Lastname">MAO</p>
    </div>

    <img
        class="JM_Logo"
        src="Media/Logo/png/logo-no-background.png"
        alt="logo"
    />

    <a href="Introduction/Introduction.html">
        <button class="explore_button" type="button">Explore</button>
    </a>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for getting back to me! I tried this and it still gives a unstyled html. Since the actual html is located within the folder "index" and is parallel to the folder "Media". Adding that / in front of the folder name shouldn't it mean its the file path starting from the root folder?

Comment: please share your folder structure

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using relative path, for example if your html file is the same folder with the css file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />`

if your css is different folder and the html in your root folder then you can try:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./YourFolderCss/index.css" />`

And if your html is within a folder but your css is different folder and parallel folder with the html folder, then you can try this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../YourFolderCss/index.css" />`

you can deep dive about absolute path or relative path, also what the meaning behind the dot "." or the double dot ".."